# NodeJS Typescript Winston: TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'TransformableInfo'

Tags: node.js, typescript, logging, metadata, winston

The below code works perfectly fine in one project:

```
const format_string_console = combine(
  format.errors({ stack: true }),
  timestamp({ format: timezonedTime }),
  format.ms(),
  format.metadata(),
  format.colorize({ all: true }),
  winston.format.printf(
    info =>
      `${info.metadata.timestamp} ${info.metadata.ms} ${info.metadata.host} pid:${process.pid} ` +
      `${info.level}: ${info.message}`,
  ),
);


...other code

const Logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'debug', // display all log levels that is 'debug' or below
  levels,
  defaultMeta: { service: 'whale', host: os.hostname() },
  transports,
});
```

However, when running the same code in another project, it gives this error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-104:~/myapp/worker$ nodemon --exec ts-node --files src/index.ts
[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting `ts-node --files src/index.ts`
/home/ubuntu/myapp/worker/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/utils/logger/devLogger.ts:48:15 - error TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'TransformableInfo'.

48       `${info.metadata.timestamp} ${info.metadata.ms} ${info.metadata.host} pid:${process.pid} ` +
                 ~~~~~~~~
src/utils/logger/devLogger.ts:48:42 - error TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'TransformableInfo'.

48       `${info.metadata.timestamp} ${info.metadata.ms} ${info.metadata.host} pid:${process.pid} ` +
                                            ~~~~~~~~
src/utils/logger/devLogger.ts:48:62 - error TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'TransformableInfo'.

48       `${info.metadata.timestamp} ${info.metadata.ms} ${info.metadata.host} pid:${process.pid} ` +
                                                                ~~~~~~~~
src/utils/logger/devLogger.ts:60:15 - error TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'TransformableInfo'.

60       `${info.metadata.timestamp} ${info.metadata.ms} ${info.metadata.host} pid:${process.pid} ` +
                 ~~~~~~~~
src/utils/logger/devLogger.ts:60:42 - error TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'TransformableInfo'.

60       `${info.metadata.timestamp} ${info.metadata.ms} ${info.metadata.host} pid:${process.pid} ` +
                                            ~~~~~~~~
src/utils/logger/devLogger.ts:60:62 - error TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'TransformableInfo'.

60       `${info.metadata.timestamp} ${info.metadata.ms} ${info.metadata.host} pid:${process.pid} ` +
                                                                ~~~~~~~~
src/utils/logger/devLogger.ts:74:15 - error TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'TransformableInfo'.

74       `${info.metadata.timestamp} ${info.metadata.ms} ${info.metadata.host} pid:${process.pid} ` +
                 ~~~~~~~~
src/utils/logger/devLogger.ts:74:42 - error TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'TransformableInfo'.

74       `${info.metadata.timestamp} ${info.metadata.ms} ${info.metadata.host} pid:${process.pid} ` +
                                            ~~~~~~~~
src/utils/logger/devLogger.ts:74:62 - error TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'TransformableInfo'.

74       `${info.metadata.timestamp} ${info.metadata.ms} ${info.metadata.host} pid:${process.pid} ` +
                                                                ~~~~~~~~
src/utils/logger/devLogger.ts:87:22 - error TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'TransformableInfo'.

87       return `${info.metadata.timestamp} ${moment(parseFloat(info.metadata.timestamp))} `;
                        ~~~~~~~~
src/utils/logger/devLogger.ts:87:67 - error TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'TransformableInfo'.

87       return `${info.metadata.timestamp} ${moment(parseFloat(info.metadata.timestamp))} `;
                                                                     ~~~~~~~~

    at createTSError (/home/ubuntu/myapp/worker/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
    at reportTSError (/home/ubuntu/myapp/worker/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
    at getOutput (/home/ubuntu/myapp/worker/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1077:36)
    at Object.compile (/home/ubuntu/myapp/worker/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1433:41)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/ubuntu/myapp/worker/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1617:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/ubuntu/myapp/worker/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/myapp/worker/src/utils/logger/index.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/ubuntu/myapp/worker/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/ubuntu/myapp/worker/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12) {
  diagnosticCodes: [
    2339, 2339, 2339,
    2339, 2339, 2339,
    2339, 2339, 2339,
    2339, 2339
  ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What is this?

There is no information about this error on the internet.

Both projects are using node version v16.6.1, and

```
"winston": "^3.3.3",

"winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.7.1",

"ts-node": "^10.9.1",

"typescript": "^3.7.2"
```

Everything is the same, and yet it gives this incredible error.

I have also tried:

"winston": "^3.8.2",

"winston": "^3.7.1",

But no luck at all.

I am pulling my hair so hard. What is this bug?

Comment: I guess you should check `winston.createLogger` options and how it differs in your projects

Comment: @ShSvyatoslav  They are the identical code as well in that regard. I have updated the question to include the `winston.createLogger` part.

Comment: And variables `levels` and `transports` do match in both of the projects?

Comment: @ShSvyatoslav, yes, they are directly copied and pasted from the project that is working well.

Comment: You can check actual versions of winston in `package.lock` or `yarn.lock`, and try to match them

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters the same issue, here is how I fixed it:

make sure that the package "logform" in installed with version "^2.3.0"

```
npm i logform@2.3.0
```

I also changed the version of

```
-    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.7.1",
+    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.6.1",
```

but I don't think this was necessary though.